# Create a zip file from a list of selected files and make the zipped file downloadable in Drupal 7

Tags: module, drupal-7, hook

I have a list of image files. I need to archive those files in zip format and make the archived file downloadable. I have seen `ArchiverZip` class defined in the `system module` of **Drupal 7**. But I couldn't be able to create a *zip* file. How can I do this in **Drupal 7** ? Is there any `hooks` or custom `modules` for this ? Please help me out with this.

**UPDATED**

Following are the codes:

```
$zip = new ArchiverZip('archive.zip');
foreach($_POST['img'] as $fid):
    $query = db_select('file_managed', 'fn')
            ->condition('fid', $fid)
            ->fields('fn', array('filename'));
    $result = $query->execute();

    foreach($result as $row) {
        if(file_exists('sites/default/files/'.$row->filename)){
            var_dump($zip->add($base_path.'sites/default/files/'.$row->filename));
        }
    }
 endforeach;
```

And this reflects the following error

*Exception*: Cannot open archive.zip in ArchiverZip->__construct() (line 91 of *basepath\modules\system\system.archiver.inc*).
Please help me with this . .

Comment: This question seems to be a duplicate of a [drupal so question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/65866/create-a-zip-file-from-a-list-of-selected-files-and-make-the-zipped-file-downloa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I missed to create the *archive.zip* file before creating the `ArchiverZip` class so the archiving operation failed previously . . Now the code will be like below:

```
$filename = 'archive.zip';
fopen($filename, 'w');
$zip = new ArchiverZip($filename);
foreach($_POST['img'] as $fid):
    $query = db_select('file_managed', 'fn')
            ->condition('fid', $fid)
            ->fields('fn', array('filename'));
    $result = $query->execute();

    foreach($result as $row) {
        if(file_exists('sites/default/files/'.$row->filename)){
            $zip->add($base_path.'sites/default/files/'.$row->filename);
        }
    }
 endforeach;
```